# how to get tar.tgz inside sub directory size without extract?

Tags: 18.04, server, openstack

Iam able to get inside content from tar.tgz file without extract file. but file size is very high so can't extract it on server.i need to get all sub directory size human readable formate from tar.tgz file without extract it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the more convenient for you will be to us mc.
mc - Midnight Commander is a clone from norton utilities.
Is a text console based utility that will allow you to browse your .tar.gz , then select the files or folders you want to restore (Key Insert over the file you want) then copy.
With Key Tab you switch from one side and the other. Normally I use the left for source and the right side for target destination.
So on the left browse to your .tar.gz file with the arrow Keys, and where you are over it press Enter. It will start opening the file. If it is very big you will need time. For 1GB it took 10 seconds on my system.

Once it is opened, browse to the selected destination with the arrow Keys, press Insert Key to mark what you want to copy, and press F5 to copy to the other side.
The line in the bottom shows what action is done by each F key. F6 RenMov, F7 Mkdir....

To exit, if F10 is intercepted by the Terminal, type **exit** and Enter.

I created a tar.gz in my Workstation to show you:

[image]

However you do need the free space on the computer browsing.